# generate an xml-schema file in JAVA code

Tags: java, xsd, database-schema

I want to generate an xml schema via java code if i have input of a database design.In the code below i have extracted input database from the user and i want to generate an xml of the given database schema.

```
public class Table
{
private ArrayList<Column> columns;
private String NAME;
private static int count=0;
public Table() 
{
columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
NAME=new String();

this.NAME="Table"+count;
count++;
}

public void AddColumn(Column column)
{
for(Column c: columns)
{
   if(c.getname().equals(column.getname())){return;}
}

columns.add(column);

}

public void SaveToFile() throws IOException
{


FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Ashad/Desktop/text.txt", true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
 bw.write("\r\n");
 bw.write(this.NAME);
 bw.write("\r\n");

for(Column c: columns)
{
 bw.write("\r\n");
    bw.write(c.getname()+"  ");

    bw.write(c.getdatatype()+"  ");


 if(c.getPK()== true)
{
    bw.write("true"+"  ");

 }    
else
{   bw.write("false"+"  ");

}
if(c.getNN()== true)
{
bw.write("true"+"   ");

}     
else
{bw.write("false"+"  "); } 



}
bw.close();
}

public boolean DeleteColumn(String name)
{
for (Column c : columns)
{
    if (c.getname().equals(name)) {return columns.remove(c);}
}
return false;
}

public void viewColumns()
{
  System.out.append(NAME+"  ");

for(Column c: columns)
{
  System.out.append("\n");
  System.out.append(c.getname()+"  ");

  System.out.append( c.getdatatype()+"  ");

if(c.getPK()== true)
{
System.out.print(true);
}     
else
System.out.print(false);  
}
}

public String getNAME() {

return NAME;
}

}



 public class Column
{
 private String name;
 private String dataType;
 private boolean PK;
 private boolean NN;


 public Column()
{
 String name=new String();
 String dataType=new String();  
 boolean PK=false;
 boolean NN=false;
}  
  public String getname(){return name;}
 public String getdatatype(){return dataType;}
 public boolean getPK(){return PK;}
 public boolean getNN(){return NN;}

 public void setname(String n){name=n;}
 public void setdatatype(Object object){dataType=(String) object;}
 public void setPK(boolean p){PK=p;}
 public void setNN(boolean n){NN=n;}


}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You can use [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) for this. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html) on how to get started with it.